# Iterate array of dictionary and filter based on matching value in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter, matching

I have a data as given below:

```
[["-MXpvzmZdbqzrjND8w9F": {
    lid = "-MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1";
    message = hi;
    timeStamp = 1617960107264;
    title = "Sambhar Dosa";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}, "-MXq5NAyrkk4ZcvRFM7T": {
    lid = "-MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1";
    message = "how ru?";
    timeStamp = 1617962828647;
    title = "Sambhar Dosa";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}], ["-MXqa5-pkC28lY_Q_hpZ": {
    lid = "-MWwEpHAhIdhN0i5sltB";
    message = "hi nice cycle";
    timeStamp = 1617971142820;
    title = "Cycle for kids";
    user = 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3;
}]]
```

Now this value is defined by the variable testarray. Name given just for convenience.
The testarray is  var testArray =  [String: [String: Any]]

Inner dictionary is defined using a struct as given below:

```
struct SomeData1
{
let dict: [String: Any]

var lid: String? { dict["lid"] as? String }
var message: String? { dict["message"] as? String }
var timeStamp: Double { dict["timeStamp"] as? Double ?? 0.0 }
var title: String? { dict["title"] as? String }
var user: String? { dict["user"] as? String }
var owner: String? { dict["owner"] as? String }
   
}
```

So testarray can also be read as var testArray =  [String: [SomeData1]]

Now as per the above data,when the lid matches with a particular value,then only those data is stored in a variable called dataToDisplay which is defined as var dataToDisplay = SomeData1

I have filtered the above data using the below code

```
     var sortStep1 = self.testArray.map {
                dict in dict.map {
                ($0.key, SomeData1(dict: $0.value))
                }.filter {$0.1.lid == self.listid}
    }

print("sortStep1 is",sortStep1)
```

the value displayed for sortStep1 is

[[("-MY5aPJ--Xoot_wlGSqS", Hungry.ChatVC.SomeData1(dict: ["owner": bPqDIJvYX7g7ZhE8ap0TgeYMYjE2, "lid": -MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1, "user": 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3, "timeStamp": 1618239661393, "message": hi, "title": Sambhar Dosa])), ("-MY5b-WT4AoWWa7c1eQT", Hungry.ChatVC.SomeData1(dict: ["title": Sambhar Dosa, "message": nice product, "user": 1QSU0c1q8QNrZzmICXGClC0o86E3, "timeStamp": 1618239817904, "lid": -MW6eEidZFCLeeZ0uBk1, "owner": bPqDIJvYX7g7ZhE8ap0TgeYMYjE2]))], []]

Here there is a null array which is also shown.i do not want this null array.i want only matching list to be displayed.
Is the code for fetching matched lid correct?

Comment: Try and add a second filter that checks that the array is not empty, something like `filter { !$0.values.isEmpty }`

Comment: to the same function?

Comment: To the code you posted yes

Comment: var sortStep1 = self.testArray.map {
                dict in dict.map {
                ($0.key, SomeData1(dict: $0.value))
                }.filter {$0.1.lid == self.listid}
    }.filter { !$0.values.isEmpty }

Comment: did you mean this way ?

Comment: If i write as mentioned above, then it is showing value of type '[(String, ChatVC.SomeData1)]' has no member 'values' error

Comment: Yes I see now that it is not a dictionary anymore so skip `values`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231109/discussion-between-saranya-and-joakim-danielson).

Comment: Add `.filter({ !$0.isEmpty })` to `sortStep1`, it should do the trick.

Comment: I need to map this value to the given struct,so that can show it easily on a tableview